# Is there a way to have a column selected by default for a multicolumn listbox?

Tags: labview

How do I make it so that everytime the front panel is called, the 1st column is highlighted/selected?

I have a multicolumn listbox in a VI. It is set to select 1 item and have the entire row selected. When the VI's front panel is called I need it to select the first row in the listbox. Right now it highlights the row that was selected the last time the VI was run. This is causing some value input errors in my code because of an associated cluster. I have tried adjusting the cluster's dependency on the listbox but it is integral to my code so this will be a better and simpler way to solve the problem.

Not attaching the VI because it will be broken due to dependency on a lot of other VIs but I have attached a picture example of expected results.
[image: Expected result]

Expected results: Highlights first row of listbox when VI is called
Actual results: Highlights the last row that was highlighted/selected when the VI was last called

Comment: Did you try with Property nodes and invoke nodes?

Comment: @billy6 I didn't try that before (extremely new to LabView so learned about property nodes after posting this questions) but tried it now by wiring to Active Cell property node. Strangely that doesn't work, though I think it should and would be a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple. Simply wire a constant numeric to the multicolumn listbox (in my case 0 is the constant because I want the first row to be highlighted). Make sure to do so somewhere where you know it will be executed as soon as the VI is run/called.

[image: See highlighted for solution]